# Using sum function with google app engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to do aggregate functions on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993059/is-there-a-way-to-do-aggregate-functions-on-google-app-engine)

Hello i've been trying to use the Sum function in my JPA application with GAE but i got this error

```
Problem with query <SELECT SUM(c.amount) FROM Cheque c>: App Engine datastore does not support operator SUM.
```

so what i want to know is there another way to do the sum and present the data in a jsp page? or i just have to forget it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do aggregate functions in the App Engine datastore; such operations are inefficient, as they require reading every single record that matches. Instead, you should compute any aggregates you need as you go - spend a little extra time when writing, to save a lot of time when reading.