# How do I find a max value in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am using go and datastore and I want to have a query where I get the max value from the datastore. I can't find anything about max values in the docs. How can I accomplish that?

I am using Google App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/

Comment: Please link to the specific library or API you are using - "datastore" is a somewhat generic term.

Comment: Are you using Google App Engine Datastore? Please tag your question accordingly. Also, do you use DB or NDB to access it?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/ I am using Google appengine

Comment: I don't really know if I am using DB or NDB, what is the default?

Comment: In the specific case of GAE Datastore, I'd recommend [tracking the max manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993059/is-there-a-way-to-do-aggregate-functions-on-google-app-engine).  I suggest this because, presumably, you're using GAED for scalability and should design accordingly.

Comment: Tracking manually is the opposite of scalability, especially since the max value can be retrieved so easily at a minimum cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct `max` function, but you can do a `your_query.Order('-the_field').Limit(1)`. Minus is for descending sorting.

This will sort the entries by `the_field` and give you the top result, which has the maximum value.

Note that if you have several entries that share the maximum value, you'll receive only one of them. This is easy to amend with a larger `Limit`.

Comment: Just to be thorough, the field has to be indexed for this to work.